# Why isn't the subjunctive ("that she be") used in "He insists that she is crazy"?

Tags: subjunctive-mood

Subjunctive clause:

> He insists that she go to the store

instead of "that she goes"

but we don't say

> He insists that she be crazy

we would normally say "that she is crazy".

Which is the correct usage and why?

Comment: The sentence "he insists that she goes to the store" seems to make sense to me...

Comment: @Artemisia But that means something completely different.  It’s asserting the speakers belief that some person really does go to the store habitually. The subjunctive version is a demand that it must be done.

Comment: I think that most people in real life would use the indicative in both cases. The subjunctive seems to be dying a slow death. In BrE it's quite common to hear phrases like 'If I was you'.

Comment: But then again, you also hear people saying 'you was ...' so perhaps it's just general ignorance as opposed to subjunctive death.

Comment: @ChrisM: The way the "past subjunctive" (that is to say, "were") is used is only barely related to the way this "subjunctive" (the one that's the same as the infinitive or "plain form" or a verb) is used. I don't think it's really useful to consider the "past subjunctive" in relation to this question. As far as I know, in British English the indicative cannot be used to replace the "plain form" subjunctive in sentences like "He insists that she go to the store": rather "that she go" would be replaced with "that she should go".

Comment: @Sumetic: in everyday speech you will hear it all the time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The insistence of the first sentence is qualitatively different from the second.

In the first, he is insisting that something **should happen in the future.** This requires the form of the verb which can conveniently be called the subjunctive.

In the second, he is insisting that something **is true in the present.** This requires the normal indicative form, which is why we say "He insists that she is crazy."

To say "He insists that she be crazy" is to insist that, while not crazy now, it is necessary for her to be crazy in the future. It's highly unusual for someone to have to go crazy.

Comment: so the usage 'He insists that she be crazy' is correct in a subjunctive sense?? 'He insists she be on the team' . So to confirm  something that has to be true in the future also qualifies as subjunctive.

Comment: Yes, but it's ridiculous. You can insist that someone should go to a store; it's unreasonable to force them to be crazy. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Yes, "he insists that she be crazy" is perfectly fine grammatically even if contexts for it might be unlikely. "He has asked them to send him a mail-order wife, and he insists that she be crazy." However, you'll find ample contexts for it if you consider "be" in passive phrases: "The public insists that the criminals be locked up."

Comment: @AndrewLeach's summary is good, and if you want to do more technical reading on it, check out [realis/irrealis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realis_mood) on Wikipedia. It also accounts for the parallel difference between sentences like "If he were at school right now, he'd be crying" (subjunctive/irrealis: he is not at school) and "If he was at school at 3 p.m., he must have made it home by now" (indicative/realis: he was indeed at school and some reasoning is being built on that fact). Note that you can replace "if" with "since" in the second case.

Comment: How about, "Before his research can be published, Roger would like to test his treatment on one more female patient, but **he insists that she be crazy**, since he already has enough results from neuro-typical patients."

Comment: When I read "He insists that she be crazy" (without any context) I thought it was using the [Habitual be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitual_be) found in AAVE. Like in the phrase ["Bitches be crazy"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Bitches%20be%20crazy).